# How do I modify the name of topic in launch file?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, roslaunch, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.

I'd like to spawn 4 mobile robots and make them move randomly on gazebo simulation.

I practiced with one robot and also set a node just publishing the topic kinds of `geometry_msgs/Twist` of `cmd_vel`.

However, it didn't move at all, because I also had attached the namespace of `/robot_0/` to all the topic wrt the spawned robot.
(so the name of `cmd_vel` changed from `name of cmd_vel` to  `/**robot_0**/name of cmd_vel`.

To discriminate 4 different kinds of `cmd_vel` topics, I just set like below:

```
<group ns="robot_0">
<param name="tf_prefix" value="robot_0" />
 <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/includes/$(arg base)_object.launch.xml">
   <!-- <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 0.5 -y 0.5 -z 0" /> -->
   <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 5.5 -y 5.5 -z 0" />
   <arg name="base" value="$(arg base)"/>
   <arg name="stacks" value="$(arg stacks)"/>
   <arg name="3d_sensor" value="$(arg 3d_sensor)"/>
   <arg name="robot_name"  value="robot_0" />
   <arg name="color" value="red" />
  <include>
</group>
```

But in the case of I made the lines wrt namespace be comment line like this,

```
<!-- <group ns="robot_0"> -->
<param name="tf_prefix" value="robot_0" />
<include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/includes/$(arg base)_object.launch.xml">
  <!-- <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 0.5 -y 0.5 -z 0" /> -->
  <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 5.5 -y 5.5 -z 0" />
  <arg name="base" value="$(arg base)"/>
  <arg name="stacks" value="$(arg stacks)"/>
  <arg name="3d_sensor" value="$(arg 3d_sensor)"/>
  <arg name="robot_name"  value="robot_0" />
  <arg name="color" value="red" />
</include>
<!-- </group> -->
```

It moved.

But I couldn't get the topic discriminated against following the namespace which means I couldn't distinguish which `cmd_vel`topic is  from which robot.

What I want to do is,

1. To make the robot move.
2. To discriminate the topics following the 4 spawned robots.

If anyone can answer or give me advice, would you please give me help?

Thanks in advance. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346746/how-do-i-modify-the-name-of-topic-in-launch-file?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can remap topic names when you [launch nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) on the command line, and also [inside launch files](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap).

You could also launch the nodes for controlling them within the same namespace section of the the launch file, and they would also have the robot details appended to their topics already.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2020-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0